# How to set keystore and truststore without using System.setProperty()

Tags: java, ssl, https, keystore, truststore

I've got a client certificate in my keystore, and server's public certificate in my truststore.

Currently, I'm setting my keystore and trustore as

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "pkcs12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", Constants.APPLICATION_HOME + File.separatorChar + this.certificateName);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", certificatePass);

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", Constants.APPLICATION_HOME + File.separatorChar + "jssecacerts");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
```

But I want to do it without using `System.setProperty()`. At least the keystore part, truststore can stay this way since it never changes. I tried this:

```
keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

InputStream keyStoreData = new FileInputStream(Constants.APPLICATION_HOME + File.separatorChar + this.certificateName);
this.keyStore.load(keyStoreData, certificatePass.toCharArray());

TrustManagerFactory trustFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustFactory.init(this.keyStore);

TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustFactory.getTrustManagers();

sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sslContext.init(null, trustManagers, null);
SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);
```

But that's setting the truststore as far as I can see, and my handshake therefore fails because now I've only got a client certificate in my truststore, and not a server certificate from my jssecacerts file. It fails with this error:

> http-bio-8080-exec-10, handling exception:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example can help you:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

import java.security.KeyStore;

import org.java_websocket.server.DefaultSSLWebSocketServerFactory;

public class EventWebSocketSecureServer extends EventWebSocketServer {

    private static EventWebSocketSecureServer instance;

    public static EventWebSocketSecureServer instance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public EventWebSocketSecureServer(int port, InetAddress ip) {
        this(port, null, null, ip);
    }

    public EventWebSocketSecureServer(int port, String keystorepath, String keystorepassword, InetAddress ip) {
        super(port, ip);

        try {
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            char ksPassword[] = keystorepassword.toCharArray();
            if (!keystorepath.equals("")) {
                KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
                ks.load(new FileInputStream(new File(keystorepath)), ksPassword);

                KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
                kmf.init(ks, ksPassword);
                TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
                tmf.init(ks);

                sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
            } else {
                sslContext.init(null, null, null);
            }
            this.setWebSocketFactory(new DefaultSSLWebSocketServerFactory(sslContext));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            com.gmt2001.Console.out.println("Secure EventSocketServer failed: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=GloriousEggroll/quorrabot/quorrabot-master/src/com/simeonf/EventWebSocketSecureServer.java